# java jbutton's mouse listener contains if/else loop jammed jvm?

Tags: java, jbutton, freeze, mouselistener

After implementing all your suggestions, the button now does not freeze the programme, but simply stops responding to mouse clicks. After pressing it, none of the others, except the "Go Back" button, work either. Previously, not even the "Go Back" button worked.
Here is the full and updatedcode:

```
package models;

// Various imports

@SuppressWarnings("unused") 
public class AskTheAdmiralFrame extends JFrame {

/**
 * Set the serial number and create components
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4057461973369708227L;
private JPanel panel;
/**
 * @wbp.nonvisual location=111,111
 */
private final JLabel textArea = new JLabel("I am Admiral Ting of the Chinese Navy.");
private final JLabel textArea2 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Battle of Yalu River interactive Historask tour.");
private final JLabel textArea3 = new JLabel("Please ask me any questions you have about the Battle of Yalu River.");
private final JLabel textArea4 = new JLabel();
private final JLabel textArea5 = new JLabel();

private final JButton button1 = new JButton("What is the Battle of Yalu River?");
private final JButton button2 = new JButton("Where was the Battle of Yalu River?(duh)");
private final JButton button3 = new JButton("When was the Battle of Yalu River?");
private final JButton button4 = new JButton("More details please.");
private final JButton button5 = new JButton("I think I know enought already. Ask me some questions");
private final JButton button6 = new JButton("More details please.");
private final JButton button7 = new JButton("More details please.");
private final JButton button8 = new JButton("More details please.");
private final JButton button9 = new JButton("What happened to the Chinese?");
private final JButton button10 = new JButton("What happened next?");
private final JButton button11 = new JButton("What happened to the Japanese?");
private final JButton button12 = new JButton("Tell me about more of the Chinese deaths.");
private final JButton button13 = new JButton("Tell me more about the admirals.");
private final JButton button14 = new JButton("Tell me more about the Chinese ships");
private final JButton button15 = new JButton("Tell me more about the Japanese ships");
private final JButton button16 = new JButton("Then why did the Chinese fleet lose even though they were so much more advanced?");
private final JButton button17 = new JButton("Go Back");

private final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
private final JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
private final JTextField textField3 = new JTextField();
private final JTextField textField4 = new JTextField();
private final JTextField textField5 = new JTextField();

private final JLabel label = new JLabel("How many ships were destroyed in the battle?");
private final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Which year did the battle take place in?");
private final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Where was the battle?");
private final JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Who was the Japanese Admiral that visited the Beiyng Fleet?");
private final JLabel label5 = new JLabel("What time was the Japanese battle flag raised?");

private int score = 0;

private String scr = Integer.toString(score);

private String ans = textField.getText();
private String ans2 = textField2.getText();
private String ans3 = textField3.getText();
private String ans4 = textField4.getText();
private String ans5 = textField5.getText();

private final JLabel labela = new JLabel("Congratualtions! You have completed the quiz:) You have scored ");
private final JLabel labelb = new JLabel(scr);
private final JLabel labelc = new JLabel();

private final ImageIcon imgicn = new ImageIcon("resources/yalubg.jpg");
private final Image img = imgicn.getImage();
private final Image imgu = img.getScaledInstance(700, 500, 0);
JLabel bg = new JLabel(imgicn);

private final ImageIcon imgicno = new ImageIcon("resources/hicon.icns");
Image imgee = imgicno.getImage();

private final ImageIcon ad = new ImageIcon("resources/Di_Ruchang.jpg");
JLabel at = new JLabel(ad);
private final JLabel adText = new JLabel("Admiral Ting Juchang");

private final ImageIcon al = new ImageIcon("resources/al.jpg");
JLabel a = new JLabel(al);
private final JLabel alText = new JLabel("Admiral Liu Buchan");

private final ImageIcon is = new ImageIcon("resources/is.jpg");
JLabel ai = new JLabel(is);
private final JLabel isText = new JLabel("Admiral Sukeyuki Itoh");

private final ImageIcon tk = new ImageIcon("resources/tk.jpg");
JLabel bt = new JLabel(tk);
private final JLabel tkText = new JLabel("Admiral Tsuboi Togo");



public void addAll(){
    if(panel.getComponents() != null){
        panel.add(a);
        panel.add(at);
        panel.add(textArea);
        panel.add(textArea2);
        panel.add(textArea3);
        panel.add(textArea4);
        panel.add(textArea5);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);
        panel.add(button5);
    }
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public AskTheAdmiralFrame() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setIconImage(imgee);
    setTitle("Ask Admiral Ting");
    setSize(1400, 1000);
    panel = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
    panel.add(textArea);
    panel.add(textArea2);
    panel.add(textArea3);
    panel.add(textArea4);
    panel.add(textArea5);
    textArea.setSize(textArea.getPreferredSize());
/**
 * Set buttons' responses   
 */
    button17.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {
            dispose();
            new HistoraskMenu();
        }
    });
    panel.add(button17);

    button1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {
            textArea.setText("The Battle of Yalu River is a battle that took place");
            textArea2.setText("between the Chinese Beiyang Fleet ");
            textArea3.setText("and the Imperial Japanese Navy.");
            textArea4.setText("Interesting?");
            textArea5.setText("");
            panel.remove(button1);
            panel.add(button5);
            panel.add(button4);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(button1);

    button2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {
            textArea.setText("Actually, the Battle of Yalu River");
            textArea2.setText("did not take place in Yalu River, ");
            textArea3.setText("but in the Yellow Sea off the mouth of the Yalu River.");
            textArea4.setText("");
            textArea5.setText("");
            panel.remove(button2);
            panel.add(button5);
            panel.add(button6);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(button2);

    button3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {
            textArea.setText("The Battle took place on the 17 of September 1894.");
            textArea2.setText("It was during the first Sino-Japanese War.");
            textArea3.setText("Sino- is a prefix meaning Chinese or China.");
            textArea4.setText("");
            textArea5.setText("");
            panel.remove(button3);
            panel.add(button5);
            panel.add(button7);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(button3);

    button4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {
            textArea.setText("The Battle of Yalu River took place in the Yellow Sea, off the mouth of the Yalu River.");
            textArea2.setText("The two fleets, the Imperial Japanese Navy and the Chinese Beiyang Fleet, met at 11.40 am in the morning.");
            textArea3.setText("Each fleet began slowely advancing towards each other.");
            textArea4.setText("It was a matter of nerves. Each fleet was out of firing range of the other");
            textArea5.setText("Neither side wanted to fire too early and waste bullets, but neither did either want to shoot too late and be caught by the other fleet.");
            panel.remove(button4);
            panel.add(button10);
            panel.add(button14);
            panel.add(button15);
            addAll();
        }
    });

    button5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {

            panel.add(textField);

            panel.add(label);

            panel.remove(textArea);
            panel.remove(textArea2);
            panel.remove(textArea3);
            panel.remove(textArea4);
            panel.remove(textArea5);

            panel.remove(button1);
            panel.remove(button2);
            panel.remove(button3);
            panel.remove(button4);
            panel.remove(button5);
            panel.remove(button6);
            panel.remove(button7);
            panel.remove(button8);
            panel.remove(button9);
            panel.remove(button10);
            panel.remove(button11);
            panel.remove(button12);
            panel.remove(button13);
            panel.remove(button14);
            panel.remove(button15);
            panel.remove(button16);

            if(ans.equals("5")){
                panel.remove(label);
                panel.remove(textField);
                panel.add(label2);
                panel.add(textField2);
                score++;
            } else { 
                panel.remove(label);
                panel.remove(textField);
                score--;
                panel.add(label2);
                panel.add(textField2);
            }

            if(ans2.equals("1894")){
                panel.remove(label2);
                panel.remove(textField2);
                panel.add(label3);
                panel.add(textField3);
                score++;
            } else {
                panel.remove(label2);
                panel.remove(textField2);
                score --;
                panel.add(label3);
                panel.add(textField3);
            }

            if(ans3.equals("yellow sea")||
                ans3 .equals("korea bay")||
                ans3.equals("The Yellow Sea")||
                ans3.equals("Korea Bay")){
                panel.remove(label3);
                panel.remove(textField3);
                panel.add(label4);
                panel.add(textField4);
                score++;
            } else {
                panel.remove(label3);
                panel.remove(textField3);
                score--;
                panel.add(label4);
                panel.add(textField4);
            }

            if(ans4.equals("Admiral Togo")
               ||ans4.equals("admiral togo")) {
                panel.remove(label4);
                panel.remove(textField4);
                panel.add(label5);
                panel.add(textField5);
                score++;
            } else {
                panel.remove(label4);
                panel.remove(textField4);
                score--;
                panel.add(label5);
                panel.add(textField5);
            }

            if(ans5.equals("12.03")
               ||ans5.equals("12.03pm")
               ||ans5.equals("12.03.p.m.")
               ||ans5.equals("12,03.pm")) {
                panel.remove(label5);
                panel.remove(textField5);
                panel.add(labela);
                panel.add(labelb);
                switch(score){
                case -5:
                    labelc.setText("points! You don't know much on the Battle of Yalu do you? "
                            + "Try learning a bit more before trying the quiz again.:(");
                    break;
                case -4:
                    labelc.setText("points! You don't know much on the Battle of Yalu do you? "
                            + "Try learning a bit more before trying the quiz again.:(");
                    break;
                case -3:
                    labelc.setText("points! You don't know much on the Battle of Yalu do you? "
                            + "Try learning a bit more before trying the quiz again.:(");
                    break;
                case -2:
                    labelc.setText("points! You don't know much on the Battle of Yalu do you? "
                            + "Try learning a bit more before trying the quiz again.:(");
                    break;
                case -1:
                    labelc.setText("points! You don't know much on the Battle of Yalu do you? "
                            + "Try learning a bit more before trying the quiz again.:(");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    labelc.setText("points! Your knowledge on the Battle of Yalu needs improvement.:(");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    labelc.setText("points! Your knowledge on the Battle of Yalu is ok, "
                            + "but you should try asking Admiral Ting a bit more"); 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    labelc.setText("points! Your knowledge on the Battle of Yalu is satisfactory. Good job:)"); 
                    break;
                case 4:
                    labelc.setText("points! Your knowledge on the Battle of Yalu is amazing!.:(");  
                    break;
                case 5:
                    labelc.setText("points! You have a perfect score!!!!:):):) Are you sure you didin't cheat?");
                    break;
                }
                panel.add(labelc);
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(button5);

    button6.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Battle took place in the Yellow Sea.");
            textArea2.setText("To be more specific, it took place in Korea Bay, ");
            textArea3.setText("which is in the northern part of the Yellow Sea");
            textArea4.setText("The Chinese were delivering reinforecements to Pyongyang ");
            textArea5.setText("and the attack was actually unprovoked.");
            addAll();
            panel.remove(button6);
        }
    });

    button7.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Battle of Yalu River was the largest naval battle ");
            textArea2.setText("of the first Sino-Japanese War. ");
            textArea3.setText("The Chinese and Japanese fleets spotted each other at 11.40am");
            textArea4.setText("The Japanese raised their battleflag at 12.03pm to signal preparation for battle.");
            textArea5.setText("And the Chinese attacked them at 12.45pm, although they were still 6km away.");
            addAll();
            panel.remove(button7);
        }
    });

    button8.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("Also, the Chinese soldiers hadn't been trained enough in gunnery.");
            textArea2.setText("It was also believed that there was a corrput saboteur within their ranks.");
            textArea3.setText("Because many of the shells had ");
            textArea4.setText("been filled with cement or porcelain.");
            textArea5.setText("Some were also of the wrong caliber and thus could not be fired.");
            addAll();
            panel.remove(button8);
        }
    });

    button9.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Chinese lost the brutal navy battle. ");
            textArea2.setText("Teir troops suffered many losses. In total, they loss");
            textArea3.setText("700 men to death and 300 to injury.");
            textArea4.setText("Five of their twelve ships were sunk.");
            textArea5.setText("All of this happened inthe duration of 5 hours.");
            panel.remove(button9);
            panel.add(button11);
            panel.add(button12);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button10.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Chinese Fleet fired first, ");
            textArea2.setText("although the Japanese ships were still 6km away. ");
            textArea3.setText("The Chinese fired too early");
            textArea4.setText("and the Japanese saw the fire and smoke from the Chinese shells");
            textArea5.setText("that fell into the water in front of them.");
            panel.remove(button10);
            panel.add(button11);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button11.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("Surprisingly, the Japanese won the short and gruesome battle.");
            textArea2.setText("Not a single of their ships were sunken and only ninety");
            textArea3.setText("of the Japanese troops were killed. Only 200 were wounded. ");
            textArea4.setText("Not a single of their ships sank. However, the crew of Matsushima were ");
            textArea5.setText("all burnt as a Chinese shell hit an ammuniton pile, causing it to burst with great heat.");
            panel.remove(button11);
            panel.add(button12);
            panel.add(button13);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button12.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The ship Lai-Yuen burnt with such heat that it glowed nearly ");
            textArea2.setText("white-hot and many of the crew burned to death. ");
            textArea3.setText("When the ship King-Yuen was hit, it started rolling from side to side until it fell over and didn't roll back. ");
            textArea4.setText("One of the two battleships, Ting, was hit 300 times by the Japanese! It's size must have it an easy target. ");
            textArea5.setText("The captain of Tsi-Yuen was decapitated for fleeing the battle and ramming another Chinese ship in the process");
            panel.remove(button12);
            panel.add(button13);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button13.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Chinese admirals were Admiral Ting and Admiral Liu.");
            textArea2.setText("The Japanese Admirals were Admiral Togo and Admiral Itoh");
            textArea3.setText("Interestingly, both Chinese admirals commited suicide by opium to uphold ");
            textArea4.setText("their honour, during the Sino-Japanese War. This refusal to give in earned ");
            textArea5.setText("them much respect from many Japanese and Chinese individuals.");
            panel.remove(button13);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button14.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Chinese fleet had 12 ships. Their ships were generally larger than the Japanese ones, ");
            textArea2.setText("and they had two huge battleships, 定远 and 鎮遠, bigger than anything the Japanese fleet had.");
            textArea3.setText("The other ten ships were a comibnation of cruisers, torpedo boats and corvet.");
            textArea4.setText("They were also equipped with ten to eight inch gun mounts. On top of that, ");
            textArea5.setText("many skilled military advisers, like Major Constantin von Hanneken, W. F. Tyler and Philo McGiffen");
            panel.add(button16);
            panel.remove(button14);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button15.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("The Japanese fleet had 12 ships.");
            textArea2.setText("Like the Chinese ships, they were relatively new, ");
            textArea3.setText("the product of the country's modernisation over the past 30 years or so.");
            textArea4.setText("Although smaller than the Chinese ships, they were faster ");
            textArea5.setText("and their sailors were more disciplined and better trained.");
            button15.remove(button15);
            addAll();
        }
    });
    button16.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent){
            textArea.setText("Well, the Japanese ships were much faster and could manouveur around and dodge ");
            textArea2.setText("the Chinese's shells and torpedoes and things.");
            textArea3.setText("Admiral Togo of the Imperial Japanese Japanese Navy had previously paid a courtesy ");
            textArea4.setText("call to the Chinese fleet and discovered that the guns were");
            textArea5.setText("dirty and some also has washing hung over them.");
            panel.remove(button16);
            panel.add(button8);
            addAll();
        }
    });

    at.setText("Admiral Ting Juchang");
    at.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    at.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    at.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(at, FlowLayout.CENTER);

    a.setText("Admiral Liu Buchan");
    a.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    a.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    a.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(a, FlowLayout.RIGHT);

    ai.setText("Admiral Sukeyuki Itoh");
    ai.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    ai.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    ai.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(ai, FlowLayout.LEADING);

    bt.setText("Admiral Tsuboi Togo");
    bt.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    bt.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    bt.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(bt, FlowLayout.LEFT);

    panel.add(bg, FlowLayout.TRAILING);

    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: You should all `break` statement in all of your `switch cases`, also to `compare` two strings you should use `equals` and not `==`

Comment: What exactly does "jammed" mean?

Answer (score 0):

First off, something that might be causing problems is that you are using == for comparing strings. In general, you should only use == for comparing primitive values. Otherwise, it's best to use the .equals method.

If you could clarify what you mean precisely by "jammed", that would help greatly in debugging this issue. Add some print statements / use the debugger to figure out precisely where you program stops. I am assuming that this is one class from some sort of GUI trivia game? From what I can tell, the if statements shouldn't be causing any problems. My guess is that there is something elsewhere in your program that is causing the issue.

Also, one other thing I noticed is that you have a space between score and -- in your if (ans2 == "1984) case.

If you can post a little more information, I could definitely help you more.

Comment: Thx. I'll post the rest of the code later. And yes, it's a GUI Trivia game for school. 
By jammed, I mean that the app freezes and the buttons become unresponsive